# Danfo JS problem reading Excel file, works with CSV

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, pandas, danfojs

I am trying to read a folder with csv and excel files with nodeJS and danfoJS.

Using danfoJS I have no problem reading the csv files but for the .xlsx files I am getting this error:

```
Error: ParamError: File not supported. file must be a url or an input File object
```

With this code:

```
const fileLocation = '/Users/riekus/Documents/notebook (analytics)/E/TIV data /test.xlsx'
let df2 = await dfd.readExcel(fileLocation)
print(df2);
```

With a csv file on the same location this works:

```
const fileLocation = '/Users/riekus/Documents/notebook (analytics)/e/TIV data /test.csv'
let df2 = await dfd.readCSV(fileLocation)
print(df2);
```

Reading the docs it is not clear to me what is going wrong here. I also tried to specify the sheet (which shouldn't be necessary) like this:

```
let df2 = await dfd.readExcel(fileLocation, {sheet: 'Sheet1')
```

Comment: I am trying to run it in JSnotebook application (analytics notebook for JS). I think  maybe jsntoebook runs the browser version of danfoJS.  Above code works in a plain nodejS file with require('danfojs-node')

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the file to `.xsl`.

The `.xslx` file format has [limited compatibility](https://blog.fileformat.com/2019/09/10/xls-vs-xlsx/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately with a .xsl file it is the same error outcome.